# Maintenance plan SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, configuration

I created a maintenance plan in the company's bank where I work, so this comes the following options:

```
  - Check Database Integrity
  - Shrink Database
  - Reorganize Index
  - Rebuild Index
  - Update Statistics
```

And after the conclusion I configured it to send e-mail to a registered operator, at first he was giving the following error:

Could not generate mail report.An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.No global profile is configured. Specify a profile name in theprofile_name parameter.

This problem could solve leaving the public operator and the default profile, according to the run history there is no longer any kind of error, yet I'm still not getting email after performing the process, someone could help me?

Comment: Maybe, if you post your code.

Comment: What code should I post ? The creation of code Maintenance plan?

Comment: The code that contains the transact sql statement or batch that is generating the error.

Comment: There is no error in the execution , only the e- mail is not sent to the end of the process

Comment: I put the creation of the operator code , it helps in any way?

Comment: Can you post the code that is supposed to send an email, but doesn't?

Comment: EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_notify_operator @name=N'TI',@subject=N'backup finished',@body=N'Backup complete'

Comment: I would guess that the problem is in the default profile, but this is more of an administration problem.  I recommend migrating this question to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think you should be shrinking database. Please read http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/